# Alternating animation loop

Tags: swift, animation, swift3, ios10, uiviewanimation

I have a repeating animation that fades a UILabel and UIImage asynchronously but I cant figure out how to make the UIImage appear for longer than the UILabel, i want the animation to alternate between the label and image so the image appears for a duration of 5 seconds and the label appears for a duration of 2 seconds:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 2.0, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse], animations: {
        self.fadeIn()
        self.fadeOut()
    }, completion: nil)
}

func fadeIn () {
    self.label.alpha = 0.0
    self.image.alpha = 1.0
}

func fadeOut () {
    self.label.alpha = 1.0
    self.image.alpha = 0.0
}
```

Comment: It looks to me that you are executing both at the same time.  Besides, you are not repeating animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you are after is multiple ways.

In the viewDidLoad instead of creating an animation block and calling your fade methods from within, just simply have separate animation blocks within each of the methods with different delay value.

So remove the UIView.animate from the ViewDidLoad and simply jus call fadeIn() and fadeOut(), and inside your fade methods you would add the UIView.animate.... and set ur desired duration and timing. This way you have a lot more control over you animation and you can tweak the values until you achieve the effect you desire.

Second option would be as previously mentioned to use key frame animation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a repeating [keyframe animation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframes) with a duration of 7 seconds, consisting of two keyframes:

- The [first keyframe](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622554-addkeyframewithrelativestarttime) starts at the start and has a duration that is 5/7 of the total duration, and fades one way.
- The [second keyframe](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622554-addkeyframewithrelativestarttime) starts 5/7 of the way through and has a duration that is 2/7 of the total duration, and fades the other way.